# Angular 6 : Data are not displayed in front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, typescript, express

Hii : I am trying to display single data by id from api, here is what i have so far,

api get method:

```
  app.get('/movies/:id', (req, res) => {
        const id =req.params.id;
        request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/'+id+'?&api_key=2931998c3a80d7806199320f76d65298', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred and handle it
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            res.send(body)
        });
    });
```

compo.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.scss']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: object;
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute, private moviesService: MoviesService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
      let id = params['id'];
      this.moviesService.getMovies(id)
      .then((movie: any) => {
        console.log(movie);
        this.movie = movie.results;
    });
   });
  }
  }
}
```

here is service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MoviesService {
  moveUrl = '/movies/';
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8000';
  constructor(private http: Http, private _jsonp: Jsonp) { }

    getMovie(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'moveUrl')
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

}
```

here is compo html:

```
<div *ngIf="movie">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">{{movie.title}} </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5">
          <img class="thumbnail" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/{{movie.poster_path}}">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7">
          <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item">Genres: <span *ngFor="let genre of movie.genres">{{genre.name}}, </span></li>    
              <li class="list-group-item">Release Date: {{movie.release_date}}</li> 
          </ul>
          <br>
          <a *ngIf="movie.homepage" href="{{movie.homepage}}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-default zero">Visit Movie Website</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>   
</div>
```

an the last if needed structure of the data tested in postman:

```
{
    "adult": false,
    "backdrop_path": "/gBmrsugfWpiXRh13Vo3j0WW55qD.jpg",
    "belongs_to_collection": {
        "id": 328,
        "name": "Jurassic Park Collection",
        "poster_path": "/qIm2nHXLpBBdMxi8dvfrnDkBUDh.jpg",
        "backdrop_path": "/pJjIH9QN0OkHFV9eue6XfRVnPkr.jpg"
    },
    "budget": 260000000,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 28,
            "name": "Action"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Adventure"
        },
        {
            "id": 878,
            "name": "Science Fiction"
        }
    ],
    "homepage": "http://www.jurassicworld.com/",
    "id": 351286,
    "imdb_id": "tt4881806",
    "original_language": "en",
    "original_title": "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
    "overview": "A volcanic eruption threatens the remaining dinosaurs on the island of Isla Nublar, where the creatures have freely roamed for several years after the demise of an animal theme park known as Jurassic World. Claire Dearing, the former park manager, has now founded the Dinosaur Protection Group, an organization dedicated to protecting the dinosaurs. To help with her cause, Claire has recruited Owen Grady, a former dinosaur trainer who worked at the park, to prevent the extinction of the dinosaurs once again.",
    "popularity": 250.012321,
    "poster_path": "/c9XxwwhPHdaImA2f1WEfEsbhaFB.jpg",
    "production_companies": [
        {
            "id": 56,
            "logo_path": "/cEaxANEisCqeEoRvODv2dO1I0iI.png",
            "name": "Amblin Entertainment",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 8111,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Apaches Entertainment",
            "origin_country": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 923,
            "logo_path": "/5UQsZrfbfG2dYJbx8DxfoTr2Bvu.png",
            "name": "Legendary Entertainment",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 103204,
            "logo_path": null,
            "name": "Perfect World Pictures",
            "origin_country": "US"
        },
        {
            "id": 33,
            "logo_path": "/8lvHyhjr8oUKOOy2dKXoALWKdp0.png",
            "name": "Universal Pictures",
            "origin_country": "US"
        }
    ],
    "production_countries": [
        {
            "iso_3166_1": "US",
            "name": "United States of America"
        }
    ],
    "release_date": "2018-06-06",
    "revenue": 0,
    "runtime": 128,
    "spoken_languages": [
        {
            "iso_639_1": "en",
            "name": "English"
        }
    ],
    "status": "Released",
    "tagline": "The park is gone",
    "title": "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
    "video": false,
    "vote_average": 6.7,
    "vote_count": 642
}
```

when I run my app the data are not displayed in front end  what am I doing wrong here? or what do I need to change , just learning guys :) thanks

Comment: I found something strange. You've got this line: `this.movie = movie.results`, but there is no `results` property in your JSON data. What do you get in the console in the line `console.log(movie)` if you get anything at all.

Comment: console.log(move) is not displating beacuse there is error while calll the function to get the movie by id , when debugging and highlighting on i see Unexpected end of input"  in this -> subscribe(movie => ,  at the end i get error occurred DOMException: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Comment: Then there's the reason. Can you tell us what URL are you calling in the end? And maybe post what the server is returning. You can check that in the network panel of your developer tools.

Comment: bro did you read well the question? you have all inforation regarding what I want to do I even provided my api  function ,  inshort everything u have right here,  can you just check my method if what am I doing is right , i just want to display a single movie returned from api in my front end , or provide me a similar example

Comment: If I had all the information I'd have answered your question. If you are getting an error calling your service, clearly you aren't calling it right, that's why I am asking what exactly are you requesting the server and what the server is returning, if it is returning something at all. Nobody here asks for information for personal pleasure, so, if you give us what I am requesting, maybe I can help you. If you don't, I am not a seer so I can't know where the error is

Comment: I want the server to return me an object by using ID ,  the problem is here : `then((movie: any) => {
            console.log(movie);
            this.movie = movie;`   I am newbie though , I dont know the right way to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173275/discussion-between-hot-zellah-and-oscar-paz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the error is.

In `getMovies` you have this:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + 'moveUrl')
```

But:

1. You're not using the `id` param at all.
2. You're concatenating a variable and a string literal, not two variables

So, in the end, whichever the `id` is, you're making a request to `http://localhost:8000moveUrl`. This is not a valid URL, and so the reason for the error you're getting.

Change the code to:

```
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + moveUrl + id)
      .toPromise()
      .then(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

This way you'll make requests to `http://localhost:8000/movies/{id}`, which is what you want.

But you must learn to use the network tool. If you had done what I asked, you would have seen the error yourself.